# How can I reverse a string using a minimum number of stacks?

Tags: string, stack, reverse

input : string arr[] = {'r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a', 't'}; and output : String arr[] = {'c', 'a', 't', 'e', 'a', 't', 'r', 'a', 't'}; how many stack is need to get this output using this give input. with explanation.

i tried everything but not get any satisfactory answer

Comment: Well that depends on how you implement it and what exactly you mean by "how many stack". If you mean the LIFO datastructure, you don't need any stack at all.

Comment: The example is reversing the order of 3 character sub-strings, not reversing a string.